# How to truncate by words not by character in Angular release 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a truncate pipe in angular and I've got code that will truncate text by a specified length of 35 words but it's currently truncating to 35 characters....

html :

```
 <p *ngIf="item.description.length > 0"><span class="body-12-bold">Description: </span><span>{{ description | truncate:[35] }}</span></p>
```

Transform Pipe :

```
    @Pipe({name: 'truncate'})
    export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
        constructor(private item: SearchEntry, private config: ConfigService) { }
        transform(value: string, args: string[]): string {
            const limit = args.length > 0 ? parseInt(args[0], 10) : 20;
            const trail = args.length > 1 ? args[1] : '...';
            return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you trim your code samples down to the smallest possible size to demonstrate the issue you are experiencing? Remove methods and other functionality to highlight the problem you are having.

Comment: Why would you make component class a component and *two* pipes simultaneously? The question you've linked certainly doesn't recommend anything like that. No wonder this doesn't work as expected. Just make them different classes.

Comment: @mlapaglia It's done.

Comment: @estus because I have two different pipes that are needed.

Comment: You need to have 3 different classes. 1 for a component. 2 for pipes.

Comment: @estus thanks but I think you're missing the point

Comment: do you have any example about different 35 words and 35 characters

Comment: I actually already figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transform(value: string, limit: number, trail: String = '…'): string {
    let result = value || '';
        if (value) {
    const words = value.split(/\s+/);
    if (words.length > Math.abs(limit)) {
        if (limit < 0) {
        limit *= -1;
        result = trail + words.slice(words.length - limit, words.length).join(' ');
        } else {
        result = words.slice(0, limit).join(' ') + trail;
        }
    }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an output as in the image below,
[image: Output without processing the data]
And if you are getting an output as in the image below,
[image: Output without handling the data]

Please use the following code :

```
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pending_line_layer" role="tabpanel">
     <table class="db table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>category</th>
        <th>data</th>
        <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let obj of pending_line">
        <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.category}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.data | slice : 0 : 21}} ... {{obj.data | slice:obj.data.length - 21 : obj.data.length}}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
```

Please not that my Angular Version is v7.3.9. For more details, check the image below:
[image: My Angular version details]

Comment: The images are making no sense

Comment: Images has been updated where changes are highlighted

Comment: And you are sure the OP or anyone can have the same use case as you? This answer doesn't bring any value